# Problemas con los botones de Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

El problema que no puedo solucionar es el siguiente:
tengo un diccionario que contiene los datos para generar botones.
(Nombre del botón, ubicación, función para el command)
Este es el parte del código:

```
"Button":[
    ("Grabar item", 80,570, "grabar_item"),
    ("Cancelar", 350,620, "cancelar"),
    ("Generar PDF", 450,620, "generar_pdf")
    ]
if widget == "Button":
i = 0
for btn in self.widgets[widget]:
    tk.Button(
    self.windows_new,
    text=btn[0], 
    font= constantes.FONT12, 
    command= lambda: globals()[btn[3]]()).place(x=btn[1], y=btn[2])
    i +=1
```

los botones se muestran perfectamente. pero al dar click en cualquier botón me dirige
a la función del ultimo botón creado (generar_pdf). Alguna idea.Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

La expresión de una función lambda no es evaluada cuando es definida, sino al ser ejecutada. En realidad es lo mismo que ocurre con el cuerpo de una función normal. Esto implica que todas ellas tengan como `btn` el ultimo item de la lista.

Puedes usar un argumento con valor por defecto para "fijar" el nombre de la función al definir la `lambda`:

```
command = lambda *_, fun_name=btn[3]: globals()[fun_name]()
```

la clave es  que el valor por defecto del argumento si es resuelto al definir la función.

Aunque si no pasas argumentos a las callbacks, no necesitas `lambda` para nada:

```
if widget == "Button":
    for text, x, y, fun_name in self.widgets[widget]:
        tk.Button(
            self.windows_new,
            text=text,
            font= constantes.FONT12, 
            command=globals()[fun_name]
        ).place(x=x, y=y)
```

Si necesitas pasar argumentos, una mejor opción es usar `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

# ...

if widget == "Button":
    for text, x, y, fun_name in self.widgets[widget]:
        tk.Button(
            self.windows_new,
            text=text, 
            font= constantes.FONT12, 
            command=partial(globals()[fun_name])
        ).place(x=x, y=y)
```

Si tiene argumentos, pasalos a `partial` después de la referencia a la función:

```
command=partial(globals()[fun_name], arg1, arg2, kwarg1=valor, ...)
```

Ademas de evitar el problema que tienes con `lambda`, es mas eficiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la solución.Claro y preciso.